# What are the attack speed breakpoints for a critical mass wizard?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-wizard

When playing a critical mass wizard, attack speed is an important stat because it increases the amount of tornadoes that you can cast. But attack speed also increases the tick rate of the tornadoes, making it even more important.

As far as I known, the tick rate does not scale linearly, but has some "breakpoints". What are those breakpoints ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From those guides

http://diablo.incgamers.com/forums/showthread.php?836968-Critical-Mass-Melee-Wizard
https://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/6794871641?page=1

As of 1.05

> Wicked Wind still works, but now you need boatloads of attack speed to
>   make it work. Attack speed plays double duty with wicked wind,
>   increasing the rate at which you can cast twisters (so you have more
>   active at a time) and also increasing the rate at which they tic. This
>   quadratic scaling with attack speed makes it the most important stat
>   for the build. Hitting the 2.73 attacks per second breakpoint is what
>   really makes a critical mass wizard shine these days.

```
 Minimum    Tick
   APS      rate
-----------------
  5.0001      72
  4.2858      60
  3.7501      52
  3.3334      45
  3.0001      40
  2.7273      36
  2.5001      33
  2.3077      30
  2.1429      28
  2.0001      26
  1.8751      24
  1.7648      23
  1.6667      22
  1.5790      20
  1.5001      19
```